# Iterating in Python lists - does it copy or use iterator?

Tags: python, list, iteration, name-binding

I have a list like this

```
a = [ [ 1,2,3 ], [ 4,5,6] ]
```

If I write

```
for x in a:
    do something with x
```

Is the first list from `a` copied into `x`? Or does python do that with an iterator without doing any extra copying?

Answer (score 10):

Python does not copy an item from a into x. It simply refers to the first element of a as x. That means: when you modify x, you also modify the element of a.

Here's an example:

```
>>> a = [ [ 1,2,3 ], [ 4,5,6] ]
>>> for x in a:
...     x.append(5)
... 
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3, 5], [4, 5, 6, 5]]
```

Comment: To explicitly respond to "does Python do that with an iterator" the answer is yes, but a Python iterator isn't quite like a C++ iterator, and the fact that `x` is not a copy is separate -- if you were to do `x = a[1]` it also wouldn't make a copy.

Answer (score 5):

The `for element in aList:` does the following: it creates a label named `element` which refers to the first item of the list, then the second ... until it reaches the last. It does not copy the item in the list.

Writing `x.append(5)` will modify the item. Writing `x = [4, 5, 6]` will only rebind the `x` label to a new object, so it won't affect `a`.

Answer (score 4):

First, those are mutable lists `[1, 2, 3]`, not immutable tuples `(1, 2, 3)`.

Second, the answer is that they are not copied but passed by reference.  So with the case of the mutable lists, if you change a value of `x` in your example, `a` will be modified as well.

Comment: It's not _exactly_ pass by reference, though that's close to what Python does. And be careful saying "change the value of x" because `x = 3` won't modify `a`.